# The cookie is not created js

Tags: javascript, php

I'm planning a registration system. Right now I'm trying to send a randomly generated session string to the mysql db; besides sending it on db I want to create a cookie with the js that contains the session string. I tried with the following code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO utenti (utente, email, password, anni, fos, pref, sessione) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('sssiiss', $ut, $em, $hash, $et, $fos, $gen, $randomString);
$stmt->execute();
    
?>
<script>
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(1202460601000));
document.cookie = "sessione=" + <?php echo $randomString ?> + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
</script>
<?php
```

but I don't know why the cookie is not generated. Would anyone know how to give me a hand?

Comment: Have you tried [`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)?

Comment: first try with direct value instead of php variable value.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Now we have tried, but the problem is the same

Comment: @aviboy2006 I tried, but nothing

Comment: Tried remove above SQL code. Might sql code has issue

Comment: @aviboy2006 I tried your solution but it didn't solve anything for me

Comment: Hi Francesco! There are few suggestions: 1. read about session in PHP https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php you don't need to create your own session_id, 2. do not mix PHP and HTML/JS in a single file, it's back practice. 

Now about your code: most probably you have JS issues (you can see it in DevTools e.g.: in Chrome browser) your $randomString variable is a string in PHP and you are trying to concatenate it with JS, it should look like this:

```
document.cookie = "sessione=<?php echo $randomString ?>; expires=" + date.toGMTString();

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php $randomString = "ffafafasfasfsafaf";
echo $randomString; ?>
<script>
var date = new Date();
var randomString = '<?php echo $randomString ?>';
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(1202460601000));
document.cookie = "sessione=" + randomString + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
</script>
```

I tried this its working for me. [image]

Comment: It Work, thank you very much! Now i found error

Comment: add your details if defer from solution for other users @FrancescoPauselli